# Transaction failure while testing firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write some tests for the cloud functions I have written, but I am facing a problem where a transaction never succeeds and ends up in an error:

`9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: the stored version (1648901730789554) does not match the required base version (0)`

Problematic code is the following:

```js
  await firebase.db().runTransaction((t) => {
    return t.get(docRef).then((doc) => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("no exist");
      }
    });
  });
```

It is run several times (checked with debugger), and then the error messages is thrown...

And the firebase test env init:

```js
export async function initialize() {
    fb.initializeTestApp({
        projectId: "my-test-project",
        auth: { uid: "alice", email: "alice@example.com" }
      });

    const testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
        projectId: "demo-project-1234",
        firestore: {
            rules: fs.readFileSync("../firestore.rules", "utf8"), // Load rules from file
            // host and port can be omitted if they can be discovered from the hub.
          },        
    });
      
    const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext(uid);
    
    const db = (alice.firestore() as unknown) as firestore.Firestore;
    firebase.db = () => db;

    return testEnv;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I currently have only one test that runs, nothing else. And firebase emulators are running, without any other app accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I have figured out that I was mixing `@firebase/testing` and `firebase-admin`, and the matter should not be used for unit testing backend functions according to [this post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1971#issuecomment-586419670).

On a side note, it seems there already is a function to create a doc iff it does not exist:

```
docRef.create(...).then(() => log("ok")).catch(() => log("Not ok"))
```